# Fast serarch of 2 dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, linq, arrays

I need a method of quickly searching a large 2 dimensional array. I extract the array from Excel, so 1 dimension represents the rows and the second the columns. I wish to obtain a list of the rows where the columns match certain criteria. I need to know the row number (or index of the array).

For example, if I extract a range from excel. I may need to find all rows where column A =”dog” and column B = 7 and column J > “a”. I only know which columns and which value to find at run time, so I can’t hard code the column index.

I could use a simple loop, but is this efficient ? I need to run it several thousand times, searching for different criteria each time.

```
      For r As Integer = 0 To UBound(myArray, 0) - 1
        match = True  
        For c = 0 To UBound(myArray, 1) - 1
            If not doesValueMeetCriteria(myarray(r,c) then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If match Then addRowToMatchedRows(r)
    Next
```

The doesValueMeetCriteria function is a simple function that checks the value of the array element against the query requirement. e.g. Column A = dog etc.

Is it more effiecent to create a datatable from the array and use the .select method ?

Can I use Linq in some way ?

Perhaps some form of dictionary or hashtable ?

Or is the simple loop the most effiecent ?

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Your code makes it seem that you need to check every column of every row, but your description makes it seem that not all columns need to be checked. Which is it?

Comment: there is the potential to check every column. Which columns are checked is a dynamic decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing *exactly* what you're trying to achieve here, a couple of things come to mind... Since you say that it is a LARGE db; you should at least sort your array. Then you can 'bubble sort' it to locate the initial selection criteria greatly reducing the forced loop-through-everything you have now.

Additionally, since this is coming from an EXCEL spreadsheet, perhaps you could let the spreadsheet do some_or_all of the work THEN get the data.

A HASTABLE requires a unique KEY, it seems like you might duplicate cell data in rows; and I know of no way to ask a HASHTABLE to return values based upon a "key that's >= 'a'"

If you are going to be doing ALOT of searching based on all kinds of varying criteria you might just save your self a lot of work and pump the data into a database table so that you can bring SQL to bear as needed.